# Interpret Scripts from vb.net

Tags: vb.net, scripting, drivers

I have a design issue i'm not quite sure how to solve. Like many other pieces of software, our software implements device drivers (that take data in our format, and convert it to CLI commands to send to a device.)

I would like to replace our current system of using in built source code to do this, with some form of script interpreter which would do the final step of sending commands to device, (or alternatively, provide back formatted commands for the main software to send to the device)

I know such a thing could be done by using an interpreter, but i'm not sure what languages there is .net support for and what exactly I would be able to do with this interpreter.

The basic problem statement is this:
I have data in XX format (VB.net objects/XML possibly)
I need to either send commands applying the settings in the XX object to a device, or send commands to read back data from the device and write it to XX object.

I want this all to occur from outside my main source code, so an end user could write and manage their own drivers.

Comment: Take a look at [Domain Specific Languages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee943825.aspx). They are a lot of work, but still a lot less than starting from scratch, and lot _safer_ than giving access to a full-on IDE environment.

Answer (score 0):

I found a very plausuable way of doing this using IronPython. 
It allows you to share variables, types, and objects with a python script and execute it inline.